# Pentaho won't register my plugin: Unexpected error registering jar plugin

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I converted the Pentaho Sample Step Plugin java project to a Kotlin project with the Gradle build tool. When I deploy the jar to the Pentaho Spoon, it gives exception:

```
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : Unexpected error registering jar plugin file: file:///home/username/Documents/pentaho/plugins/folder-name/myjar-name.jar
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.StepPluginType.extractID(StepPluginType.java:149)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.BasePluginType.handlePluginAnnotation(BasePluginType.java:750)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.BasePluginType.registerPluginJars(BasePluginType.java:718)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.BasePluginType.searchPlugins(BasePluginType.java:184)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.registerType(PluginRegistry.java:605)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.init(PluginRegistry.java:577)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.init(PluginRegistry.java:545)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:145)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:100)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:81)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$1.call(Spoon.java:643)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$1.call(Spoon.java:635)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2020/04/06 16:27:43 - General -         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Why does Pentaho not register my plugin?

My PDI version: `9.0.0.0-423`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same dehavior and I follow this solution
https://community.hitachivantara.com/s/question/0D52S00008AkM8DSAV/pdi-startup-fail-unde-macos-catalina.

Accordingly Matt Velez he said:

1. Go here:
   https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html#Latest_Release
2. Click the latest version number (it was 4.16 for me) Click 'SWT Binary and Source' on the left sidebar.
3. Download and unzip the Mac version.
4. Move the swt.jar file in the archive to the data-integration/libswt/osx64 folder.
5. Run PDI.